# Detect when Apache Cordova and JQuery are both ready

Tags: javascript, cordova-3

I have built apache cordova using the npm functions and have opened it in Eclipse, I have edited it and so far the changes seem to be working okay. I want to now set up some bindings on the buttons I have added to the interface and want to make sure $(document).ready() has fired. I am trying to keep the structure that came with the original index.js file but I'm not used to this xyz: function() syntax. I thought I had it right but its not returning an alert.

```
var app = {

initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},

onDeviceReady: function() {
    $(document).ready(this.onQueryReady);
},

onQueryReady: function() {
    alert('jQuery Ready');
}

};
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(function() {...})` is essentially `document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", completed, false )` or `window.addEventListener( "load", completed, false )`. It is just another event binding. So you can just move your `$.ready()` into `bindEvents()` like this

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        $(document).ready(this.onQueryReady);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
    },

    onQueryReady: function() {
        alert('jQuery Ready');
    }
};
```